# Matching non-english characters with \w

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex, nsregularexpression

I'm trying to extract some names from html. For example, the string may look like this:

```
Doe, J
```

the pattern I'm using is:

```
\w+, \w
```

Everything works fine as long as the names consists of the letters from english alphabet. The same pattern doesn't match spanish or polish names:

```
Cortázar, J
Król, S
```

Obviously the specific characters are problematic. Any ideas what to do to make \w match these characters? I looked into the [NSRegularExpression options](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/NSRegularExpressionOptions), but I don't think it supports it. Or maybe I'm missing the point here and I should come up with smarter regular expression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NSRegularExpression` does not seem to match unicode characters in a good way, what you could do is instead match everything up to a delimiter, which I assume you have?

```
^(\X+?),$
```

This would create a capture group with the results you want and it should match unicode as well.

You can also use the matching character expressions `\u` or `\p`. This can be seen [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html#jumpTo_1). This [article](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html) describes them.

Comment: In the article you linked I actually found the proper solution, since NSRegularExpression supports \X I can use it as the unicode version of the dot(.), just make it not greedy.

Comment: `NSRegularExpression` on the contrary seems to match Unicode characters just fine - at least the ones I have tried. For one example, you can see my answer. Or, even better, try for yourself :-) There is one thing to note, though: `\b` needs the `w` flag (as in `(?w:)` to detect word boundaries with non-ASCII characters. More information here: http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/regexp

Comment: @Monolo, Agree. That's because `\w` is defined as `[\p{Ll}\p{Lu}\p{Lt}\p{Lo}\p{Nd}]` on iOS (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsregularexpression?language=objc).

Answer (score 1):

One of the problems with `\w` is that you need to get it into a string with all the backslashes properly escaped.

```
NSArray *names = @[@"Cortázar, J", @"Król, S", @"Don't Match This", @"Doe, J", @"Høegh, K"];

NSString *pattern = @"\\w+, \\w";
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"self MATCHES %@", pattern];

NSArray* result = [names filteredArrayUsingPredicate: pred];
```

It correctly matches the names, but leaves out the "wrong" string at index 2.

This shows that you can match the strings with an  `NSRegularExpression` as the predicate engine uses the same regular expression syntax.

*Edited to add:*

If you insist on using an `NSRegularExpression` directly, then you can see it work with a little more code:

```
// The names and pattern variables taken from code above

NSError *error = NULL;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern
                                                                       options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                                                         error:&error];    

for (NSString *string in names) {

    NSRange rangeOfFirstMatch = [regex rangeOfFirstMatchInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];
    if (!NSEqualRanges(rangeOfFirstMatch, NSMakeRange(NSNotFound, 0))) {
        NSString *result = [string substringWithRange:rangeOfFirstMatch];
        NSLog(@"Match: '%@'", result);
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"No match: '%@'", string);
    }
}
```

You will see that it matches the names, with either pure ASCII or various European accented characters, but it does not match the string "Don't Match This".

Comment: I'm not sure what this has to do with my question, is there anything I could do to to make \w match the names with NSRegularExpression?

Comment: @lawicko It has a lot to do with your question, I hope - the predicate engine is just a simpler way to code it for a quick proof of concept. I re-wrote the example to not use a literary regex pattern in the format string, so the two examples are now directly comparable. Anyway, edited the answer to add an example done with `NSRegularExpression`. It just takes more code to show that it works.

Comment: This must be magic :) The same matches I tried to do yesterday now magically work, I have no idea why :) Thanks for the explanation, I actually don't use \w anymore anyway, because I found that my data sometimes comes with compound names, so I'm using more general match to filter it. Anyway, it looks like \w matches the unicode characters after all, and also it's good to know that NSPredicate uses the same regex engine underneath.